# Backref not adding backref to all references of \cite command in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I'm using `backref` to add the page number in front of each citations in the bibliography. I also needed to add the the word 'page' before each backref hyperlink.

#### `main.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,pagebackref]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*\backref[1]{\ifx#1\relax \else (page #1) \fi}

\begin{document}

Here goes the main text that I want to cite a few articles \cite{firstKey, secondKey, thirdKey, fourthKey, fifthKey, sixthKey}.

\bibliography{sample.bib} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

#### `sample.bib`:

```
@article{firstKey,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{secondKey,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{thirdKey,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{fourthKey,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{fifthKey,
  title={Cavity optomechanics},
  author={Aspelmeyer, Markus and Kippenberg, Tobias J and Marquardt, Florian},
  journal={Reviews of Modern Physics},
  volume={86},
  number={4},
  pages={1391},
  year={2014},
  publisher={APS}
}


@article{sixthKey,
  title={Optomechanics},
  author={Marquardt, Florian and Girvin, Steven M},
  journal={Physics},
  volume={2},
  pages={40},
  year={2009},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

The document looks like this:

---

---

Here goes the main text that I want to cite a few articles **[1-6]**.

#### References

[1] A. Einstein, \Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]," Annalen der Physik, vol. 322, no. 10, pp. 891{921, 1905. **(page 1)**

[2] P. A. M. Dirac, The Principles of Quantum Mechanics. International series of monographs on physics, Clarendon Press, 1981.

[3] D. Knuth, \Knuth: Computers and typesetting."

[4] D. E. Knuth, Fundamental Algorithms, ch. 1.2. Addison-Wesley, 1973.

[5] M. Aspelmeyer, T. J. Kippenberg, and F. Marquardt, \Cavity optomechan- ics," Reviews of Modern Physics, vol. 86, no. 4, p. 1391, 2014.

[6] F. Marquardt and S. M. Girvin, \Optomechanics," Physics, vol. 2, p. 40, 2009. **(page 1)**

---

---

## My Question

Why there is no backref in front of refs 2-5 of references section?

Comment: please supply an example that shows the probem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK

Comment: texlive has a `sample.bib` (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/gloss/sample.bib)  but it does not have the entries that you show

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I add it to the post

Comment: it is only backref the visible numbrs 1 and 6 if you don't compress eg have `\cite{firstKey}\cite{secondKey}\cite{thirdKey}\cite{fourthKey}\cite{fifthKey}\cite{sixthKey}.` they all work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is that I need the compressed format of refs in the main text, i.e. the range [1-6] instead of [1][2][3][4][5][6].

Comment: sure, that was just a debugging hint for someone in a better timezone to look. backref is such a hack though, it may not want to work easily. You can always simply edit the bbl and add links by hand